# How to join two JSON array element into one JSON array?

Tags: json

**Suppose JSON Array:**

```
JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();

[{"Name":"deep","Id":1001}]

JSONArray list2 = new JSONArray();

[{"Dept":"dept123"}]
```

**I want to get**

```
[{"Name":"deep","Id":1001,"Dept":"dept123"}]
```

Comment: Is the structure same?

Answer (score 0):

```
1. for i in range(0, len(list1)):
2.     currentVal <- list1.get(i) //get ith element
3.     currentVal.append(list2.get(i))
```

The concept is to iterate over one of the array and access the dictionary of the ith element of the both the arrays and in the list1's dictionary, append the dictionary that you got from list2

Comment: Error Occur.. please let me details

Comment: what is the error and what language are you writing your code in?

Comment: Describe in details that is write full program